# How to check PHP filecode syntax in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, syntax

I am in a need of running the PHP parser for PHP code inside PHP. I am on Windows, and I have tried

```
system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PHP\\php.exe -l \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache/htdocs/a.php\"", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

without luck. The parameter -l should check for correct PHP syntax, and throw errors if some problems exist. Basically, I want to do something similar to this picture:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mpsoftware.dk](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/images/phpdesigner7/phpdesigner7-php-syntaxerror.png))</sub>

That is, to be able to detect errors in code.

Comment: What problem are you facing with -l option ?

Comment: I'm not getting *any* feedback out from php.exe... I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
<?php

$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.php';

//$output will be filled with output from the command
//$ret will be the return code
exec('php -l ' . escapeshellarg($file), $output, $ret);

//return code should be zero if it was ok
if ($ret != 0) {
    echo 'error:';
    var_dump($output);
} else {
    echo 'ok';   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The runkit extension provides a function to do that:

[runkit_lint_file()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-lint-file.php)

If you can not use runkit then you only other way is to do what you already tried:

```
echo passthru("php -l ".__FILE__);
```

Try fixing your path with [realpath()](http://www.php.net/manual/function.realpath.php) if it does not work.